# User profile picture overtaken by default picture (laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to add a default profile picture to new registered users. Therefore I add this code below:

```
<a href="#change_photo" data-toggle="modal">
@if (file_exists(public_path().'/images/'.$user->photo))
    <img src="{{ asset('images/'.$user->photo) }}" class="img-circle" alt="Add picture">
@else
    <img src="{{ asset('images/profile_picture.jpg') }}" class="img-circle" alt="Add picture">
@endif
```

It worked well, however all users' customized profile pictures are now displaying the default picture.

Laravel version 5.2.45 & PHP version 7.2. Thank you

Comment: You have checked that why it is not going in if condition? The image is not at that location or something else?

Comment: `echo public_path().'/images/'.$user->photo` echo this line and check the complete path or hit this path on browser

Comment: I got a wrong public_path, it's pointing me out of the public_html folder -> 'home/website/public_html/.../images/profile_picture.jpg'. How to correct this without override the public_path? Thank you